# How to concatenate variable to Range Shortcut [ ]?

Tags: excel, vba

I prefer to use Range Shortcut [ ] instead of Range(" ").

But I cannot concatenate variable to it.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Select    ‘This works
```

`ActiveSheet.[A2:A & LastRow].Select`    ‘**not works**

I got error Object required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add variables within the brackets. That's why it's returning the object required error.

ExcelHero did tests and found that the brackets run slower than when range is clearly defined in the code:
http://www.excelhero.com/blog/2010/06/when-working-in-vba-we.html

Comment: Correct. That's what I was trying to explain to the OP. One cannot use variable within the brackets.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Evaluate`  to do what you want to do

```
ActiveSheet.Evaluate("A2:A" & lastRow).Select
```

> Using square brackets (for example, "[A1:C5]") is identical to calling
> the Evaluate method with a string argument.

Further reading

[refer-to-cells-by-using-shortcut-notation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/refer-to-cells-by-using-shortcut-notation)

[excel.application.evaluate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate)

**PS** As the OP is after having  a string variable in the expression with `[]` and as I do not think that this is possible another quote from the documentation to support my point of view.

> The advantage of using square brackets is that the code is shorter.
> The advantage of using Evaluate is that the argument is a string, so
> you can either construct the string in your code or use a Visual Basic
> variable.

Comment: Evaluate is another way , But it doesn't answer the question

Comment: Yes, I think, it does as `[ ]` is identical to calling the Evaluate as stated in the documentation. And I do not  think that there is another way using a string variable in a `[ ]` expression. You have to use `Evaluate` explicitly. But maybe someone else can shed more light on the issue.

Comment: The advantage of using square brackets is that the code is shorter , and that I aim to.

Comment: That is your perspective. I always prefer to have proper clear definitons. Example: `[sin(45)]` is also valid but does not refer to a range.

Comment: Bracket expressions in their minimal form can be helpful if you know what your are doing, but may induce to forget completely about qualifying range references, like at least `[Sheet1!A2]` or an unwieldy `[[test.xlsm]Sheet1!$A$4]`. -  Upvoted your post as you use the **worksheet related** form of `Evaluate` which *fully qualifies* simple range indications in the string argument subsequently, e.g. in `ws.Evaluate("A2")` or `Sheet1.Evaluate("A2")`. Of course it's fair to mention that you can do something similar using `[ ... ]`   via `ws.[A2]` or `Sheet1.[A2]` @Storax